# How to pull from github to server (Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 11 commits.)

Tags: git, github

I uses github to transfer files from local to server. I just uses

```
git pull origin master
```

on server to pull from github but now I have made some changes on files on server (edited few/deleted few as well as few are untracked now).

Now I have pushed the latest working code from local to github and I was thinking of just doing **git pull origin master**. Is this the right way to do it ? will it take care of all the conflicts and the message that I am getting - "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 11 commits" ?

I am just worried that git pull origin master don't create multiple merge files as the server is live!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a 'git pull' this will bring the changes from Github. If there are conflicts you will be prompted to resolve them.  The 'ahead by 11 commits' just means that you have 11 commits in your local trio that after not in GitHub. To fix that you will want to do 'git push' to send those commits to GitHub.

If you want to not have the merge commit appear from the 'pull', you can do 'git pull --rebase' or 'git rebase origin master' This will apply the 11 commits that you are ahead after bringing in the changes.

Comment: Thanks Schleis, I just want the files at github to be downloaded at server without any conflicts and really don't have (want to) nothing to push on the server. Can you tell me which is the most ideal way to do this ?

Comment: The most ideal way is you make no changes to files on the server. You make the changes and push to GitHub from elsewhere. You only ever pull in the changes. Only pulling, so then, you can't have a conflict.

Comment: yes, this was a mistake, so for the current problem, what should I do ? should I do the pull origin master ?

Comment: Yeah, the do 'git pull' and then 'git push' to get GitHub up-to-date. That will get things taken care of.